# Function Rcpp::match does not work when I updated to R 4.0.4

Tags: rcpp

Today I updated to R 4.0.4 and the Rcpp::match does not work well. I think the version update is the reason but not sure about it. Any suggestion is wonderful.
(EDIT: I just tried in R 3.6.3 and the following codes work well)

**(EDIT v2: Updating the Rstudio to the newest version solved this issue)**

The below is the **test_RcppMatch.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector test(Rcpp::CharacterVector SampleInModel,
                         Rcpp::CharacterVector SampleInPlink)
{
  Rcpp::IntegerVector posSampleInPlink = Rcpp::match(SampleInModel, SampleInPlink);
  return posSampleInPlink;
}


// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
test(c(1,3,5,7,9),1:10)
*/
```

The below is the error information

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('C:/Users/wenji/OneDrive/Desktop/test_RcppMatch.cpp')

> test(c(1,3,5,7,9),1:10)
Error in test(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), 1:10) : 
  SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'
```

The below is my platform

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.6 GRAB_0.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4    tools_4.0.4       data.table_1.14.0
[4] packrat_0.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Could something be funny with your installation?  Do you maybe have two paths for packages?

It works well here (R 4.0.4, Ubuntu 20.10, everything current)

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/66359002/question.cpp")

> test(c(1,3,5,7,9),1:10)
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
>
```

I left your code essentially unchanged (but moved two curlies, and removed comments and the `using` as you properly prefixed all identifiers).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector test(Rcpp::CharacterVector SampleInModel,
                         Rcpp::CharacterVector SampleInPlink) {
  Rcpp::IntegerVector posSampleInPlink = Rcpp::match(SampleInModel, 
                                                     SampleInPlink);
  return posSampleInPlink;
}

/*** R
test(c(1,3,5,7,9),1:10)
*/
```

And thanks for posting code!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just updated my Rstudio to the newest version and the error does not come up. The idea to update Rstudio is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860755/rstudio-markdown-crash-error-in-function-srcref-unimplemented-type-29

Comment: I very much doubt it has anything to do with it but hey a) you have it working now so who cares and b) I also tend to run RStudio dailies (updated maybe monthly) so I may have been on newer versions for a bit anyway...